# Importing latitude and longitude into a location(LatLonPointSpatialField class) field in Solr

Tags: solr, location, import-csv

Alright, I am looking for general guidelines on how to import a CSV file containing the following fields

```
poi_name, latitude, longitude
```

into a Solr (7.x) core to perform geo queries? What is the right way to achieve this? I tried

- using the `bin/post`import creates a useless schema where all the fields are multivalued. Obviously no location field is being created.
- doing the same but creating a schema for the 3 fields via the admin UI and I get `"Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id"`. I would like to get the functionality where the `id` is automatically populated with a random `uuid`.
- and lastly and the most important is how to "compute" a LatLonPointSpatialField from the `latitude` and `longitude`. Via the UI there was no way to create a 4th field that utilizes other fields.

Do I really need to go trough the trouble of defining a `DataImportHandler` to do this or it is sufficient to create a schema for all this?

What if the latitude and longitude are already there and I am trying to update the schema with the location field at a later time?

Can't find a good example for doing this, however there is an old example where the `location` field is automatically composed if latitude and longitude have predefined names with a suffix something like `location_1_coordinate` and `location_2_coordinate` this seems silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - you'll have to define a location field. The schemaless mode is made for quick prototyping, if you need more specific fields (and be sure that the fields get the correct type in production), you'll have to configure them explicitly. Use [the LatLonPointSpatialField type](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/field-types-included-with-solr.html) for this, and make it single valued.

First define the field type to use (these are [adopted from the Schema API documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html)):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{   "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"location_type",
     "class":"LatLonPointSpecialField"
```

}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema

Then add a field with that type:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"location",
     "type":"location_type",
     "stored":true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema
```

The two other issues can be fixed through a [custom update chain](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) (you provide the name of the chain as the `update.chain` URL parameter when indexing the document).

To automagically assign a guid to any indexed document, you can use the [UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory.html). Give the field name (`id`) as the `fieldName` parameter.

To get the latitude and longitude concatenated to a single field with `,` as the separator, you can use a [ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html). The important thing here is that it concatenates a list of values given for a single valued field into a single value - it does not concatenate two different field names. To fix that we can use a [CloneFieldUpdateProcessor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) to move both the latitude and longitude value into a separate field.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="populate-location">
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <arr name="source">
      <str>latitude</str>
      <str>longitude</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="dest">location</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="delimiter">,</str>
  </processor>
</updateRequestProcessorChain
```

If you add the location field later and already have the data in your database, this won't work. Solr won't touch data that has already been indexed, and you'll have to reindex to get your information processed and indexed the correct way. This is true regardless of how you get content into the `location` field.

The old example is probably the other way around - earlier you'd send a latlon pair, and it'd get indexed as two separate values - one for latitude and one for longitude - under the hood. You could probably hack around that by sending a single value for each, but it was really meant to work the other way around - sending one value and getting it indexed as two separate fields. Since the geospatial support in Lucene (and Solr) was just starting out, the already existing types were re-used instead of creating more dedicated types.

Comment: I ended up creating an `updateRequestProcessorChain` that combines the UUID and Location; UUID works very well but the location processor gave me 
"ERROR: [doc=2fb5b18a-89c8-4b92-a2a1-98e0e1e81a32] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field location: [22.9308852, 39.3724824]",
and after I changed location as multivalue I was getting
 Error adding field 'location'='[22.9308852, 39.3724824]' msg=Unable to parse shape given formats \"lat,lon\", \"x y\" or as WKT because java.text.ParseException: Unknown Shape definition [22.9308852]" Thougts?

Comment: I just realized that I should NOT define the location as `multivalue` that is why it cannot parse it into a shape definition. But if I don't do that I get the `multiple values encountered for non multiValued field location`. I feel that am pretty close to the solution here as long as I can concatenate the two fields :)

Comment: The problem was in the way the cloning and concatenation was defined. I got the  idea from here https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/01/31/concatenating-fields-with-apache-solr it is working perfect now! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Just conclude and aggregate the answer for anyone interested this is the solution I came to following MatsLindh suggestion. Context: CentOS 7 and Solr 7.5

- Sample.csv content

---

`name,lon,lat,
A,22.9308852,39.3724824
B,22.5094530,40.2725792`

---

- relevant portion of the schema (`managed-schema` file)

`<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
...
<field name="lat" type="string" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location" type="location" multiValued="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="lon" type="string" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

---

- `solrconfig.xml`

```html
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid-location">
      <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">id</str>
      </processor>
        <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
            <str name="source">lat</str> 
            <str name="dest">location</str> 
        </processor> 
        <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
            <str name="source">lon</str> 
            <str name="dest">location</str> 
        </processor> 
       <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
            <str name="fieldName">location</str> 
            <str name="delimiter">,</str> 
        </processor>
      <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
      <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
     </updateRequestProcessorChain>
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
      <str name="update.chain">uuid-location</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

and to import the sample file into the core run the following in bash

`/opt/solr/bin/post -c your_core_name /opt/solr/sample.csv`

---

And if you wonder how to query that data use

`http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core_name/select?&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt%20sfield=location}&pt=42.27,-74.91&d=1`

where `pt` is the lat-long point and `d` is the distance in kilometers.